# LinkedList of objects added in alphabetical order according to object param

Tags: sorting, object, parameters, linked-list, alphabetical

What would be the best way to add objects into my LinkedList in alphabetical order of one of the objects parameters? I have a class that takes in last name, first name, and some other stuff. I've made an object of that class and the parameters are all user submitted, and I have to store every object that's made into a LinkedList. The objects must be added to the linked list in alphabetical order according to the last name. What would be the best way to do this?

Thanks!!

Comment: It's a small part of a project I have to do. So far I have a LinkedList that adds an object, but it simply adds the object at the end of the list. It need to add at the right spot according to the last name parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a binary search through your list using the “[compareTo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29)” function to find the correct index in which to insert the new value.

The binary search consists in comparing the middle element key value with a given key, in this case, your new element. If the key match you are done, that is the correct index, if it does not but the value is greater than your key value you have to do the search again with the left half of the array, on the contrary, you do the search again with the right half